# How to let Emacs zoom to full screen on Mac OS X?

Tags: emacs, fullscreen

How to let Emacs zoom to full screen on Mac OS X?

I am using GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.29) on Mac OS X 10.6.8.